# Calling haskell code from OCaml using FFI

Tags: haskell, ocaml, ffi

I would like to expose a function from a Haskell source library using FFI and use it in OCaml code. I saw various examples using the `foreign export ccall`syntax in Haskell which I believe exports the function for usage in C. Is there something similar for OCaml? What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Probably one needs to use C as a lingua franca, and doing all the required marshalling Haskell<->C<->Ocaml. I don't think there's anything easier, as Haskell and Ocaml have quite different runtime systems. For instance, a pair of integers has a very different representation in the two languages, so one needs to convert accordingly.

Comment: See [interfacing C with OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html) in the manual and the [`ctypes` library](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes).

Answer (score 0):

If this `foreign export ccall` works as I think it should, then you should end up with a shared object file roughly identical to what would be generated by a C compiler. Just pretend that's the case and feed that object file to your linker.